# Understanding the formation of SimpleXMLElement object in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml

I was curious to know how a SimpleXMLElement object was formed in PHP from an XML document, but I think there might be something in this process that is unknown to me.

When we loop through an object in PHP, the public properties are iterated over. So if the first property is an array, then we should need another loop inside our first loop to iterate over it, however, it doesn't seem to be the case about a SimpleXMLElement object. Look at this object for instance:

```
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["user"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (3) {
      ["firstname"]=>
      string(6) "Sheila"
      ["surname"]=>
      string(5) "Green"
      ["contact"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (3) {
        ["phone"]=>
        string(9) "1234 1234"
        ["url"]=>
        string(18) "http://example.com"
        ["email"]=>
        string(18) "pamela@example.com"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (3) {
      ["firstname"]=>
      string(5) "Bruce"
      ["surname"]=>
      string(5) "Smith"
      .
      .
      .
```

It contains a "user" property in which there's an array(of 5 elements). So when we loop through this object, we should get this error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in ...

I've tested this in this snippet:

```
$var = (object)array(
   'user'=>['joe','mia'],
);
```

Now this loop gives the error I just mentioned above:

```
foreach ($test as $property => $val){
    echo $property.':'.$val.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmliterator.getchildren.php

Comment: Your trying to equate how an object is held internally with how the class behaves at the surface.  The main concept is to work with XML elements through the SimpleXML methods and don't worry about the object internal representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$val` in the loop is an array, so you can not echo it. Use `print_r($val)` to show its value.

```
foreach ($test as $property => $val){
    echo $property.':';
    print_r($val);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth trying to understand how the basic SimpleXML processing works, trying to hack around the internal structures of the objects isn't going to help.  When trying to access elements, use `->elementName`

A simple mock up of the data you probably has...

```
$data = "<base>
    <user>
        <firstname>Sheila</firstname>
        <surname>Green</surname>
        <contact>
            <phone>1234 1234</phone>
        </contact>
    </user>
</base>";
```

If you wanted to print out all of the elements under `<user>`, then you can use `foreach()` and use `->user->children()` as in...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
//print_r($xml);

foreach ( $xml->user->children() as $tag => $value )  {
    echo $tag."-".$value.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which outputs...

```
firstname-Sheila
surname-Green
contact-
```

As contact is a structure in itself, you could add

```
if ( $value->count() > 0 )  {
    foreach ( $value->children() as $tag => $sub )  {
        echo $tag."-".$sub.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

To allow you to print that out.